# Call to a member function prepare() on null Error on my code

Tags: php

Here is my code i am getting Call to a member function prepare() on null Error on my code can anyone please help me on this issue. This issue suddenly happened few days before it was working fine but now its showing when i try to add user name and password into text fields

```html
class LoginSystem {

 /* Start Config */

 private $dbhost    = ""; 
 private $dbport    = ""; 
 private $dbuser    = ""; 
 private $dbpass    = ""; 
 private $dbname    = ""; 
 private $dbtable    = ""; 
  private $pages     = ""; 
    private $news    = "";
 private $doct    = "";
 private $health    = "";
 private $dept    = "";
 private $features   = "";
 private $epages    = "";
 private $tips     = ""; 
 private $core     = ""; 
 private $banner    = ""; 
 
 private $secureKey  = ""; 
 private $passwordSalt  = ""; 
 private $company  = "xyz"; 
 var $phpsessionstart = true; 
 var $emailLogin   = false; 
 var $rememberMe   = false; 
 
  
  
  public $staticPages  = array(
   "/register.php"
   ); 
  
  private $loginPage  = "/index.php"; 
  private $homePage   = "/home.php"; 
 
 public $loggedIn   = false;
 public $db    = true;
 public $user   = false;
 private $cookie;
 private $session;
 private $remCook;
 private $dbh;
 private $initCalled = false;
 
 public function __construct(){
  if($this->phpsessionstart == true){
   session_start();
  }
  
  try{
   
   array_push($this->staticPages, $this->loginPage);
   
   $this->dbh   = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->dbname};host={$this->dbhost};port={$this->dbport}", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass,array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
  ));
   $this->db    = true;
   $this->cookie  = isset($_COOKIE['logSyslogin']) ? $_COOKIE['logSyslogin'] : false;
   $this->session  = isset($_SESSION['logSyscuruser']) ? $_SESSION['logSyscuruser'] : false;
   $this->remCook  = isset($_COOKIE['logSysrememberMe']) ? $_COOKIE['logSysrememberMe'] : false;
   
   $encUserID    = hash("", "{$this->secureKey}{$this->session}{$this->secureKey}");
   $this->loggedIn = $this->cookie == $encUserID ? true : false;
   
   
   if($this->rememberMe === true && isset($this->remCook) && $this->loggedIn === false){
    
    $encUserID   = hash("", "{$this->secureKey}{$this->remCook}{$this->secureKey}");
    $this->loggedIn = $this->cookie == $encUserID ? true : false;
    
    if($this->loggedIn === true){
     $_SESSION['logSyscuruser'] = $this->remCook;
    }
   }
   
   $this->user = $this->session;
   return true;
   
  }catch( PDOException $e ) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 
 public function init() {
  if( $this->loggedIn && array_search($this->curPage(), $this->staticPages) !== false ){
   $this->redirect($this->homePage);
  }elseif( !$this->loggedIn && array_search($this->curPage(), $this->staticPages) === false ){
   $this->redirect($this->loginPage);
  }
  $this->initCalled = true;
 }
 
 
 public function login($username, $password, $cookies = true){
  if($this->db === true){
   
   /* We Add LIMIT to 1 in SQL query because we need to just get an array of data with key as the column name. Nothing else. */
   if($this->emailLogin === true){
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `password`, `password_salt` FROM `{$this->dbtable}` WHERE `username`=:login OR `email`=:login ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1";
   }else{
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `password`, `password_salt` FROM `{$this->dbtable}` WHERE `username`=:login ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1";
   }
   
   $sql = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
   $sql->bindValue(":login", $username);
   $sql->execute();
   
   if($sql->rowCount()==0){
    return false;
   }else{
    /* Get the user details */
    $rows   = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $us_id  = $rows['id'];
    $us_pass  = $rows['password'];
    $us_salt  = $rows['password_salt'];
    $saltedPass = hash('', "{$password}{$this->passwordSalt}{$us_salt}");
    
    if($saltedPass == $us_pass){
     if($cookies === true){
      
      $_SESSION['logSyscuruser'] = $us_id;
      setcookie("logSyslogin", hash("", $this->secureKey.$us_id.$this->secureKey), time()+3600*99*500, "/");
      
      if( isset($_POST['remember_me']) && $this->rememberMe === true ){
       setcookie("logSysrememberMe", $us_id, time()+3600*99*500, "/");
      }
      $this->loggedIn = true;
      if( $this->initCalled ){
       $this->redirect($this->homePage);
      }
     }
     return true;
    }else{
     return false;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to read this with all the extra unneeded code, can you get rid of all the unimportant stuff and fix your formatting? Edit: found it after I posted removed extra question

Comment: Yes i am posting again

Comment: @DaveGoten please check

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not an answer but needed the space to type it all

After stripping down the code some and adding debug echos:

```
<?php
class LoginSystem {

    /* Start Config */

    private $dbhost             = "";
    private $dbport             = "";
    private $dbuser             = "";
    private $dbpass             = "";
    private $dbname             = "";
    private $dbtable            = "";
    private $dbh;
    public  $db                 = true;

    public function __construct(){

        try{
            echo '<p>trying to create connection</p>'; // Debug echo
            $this->dbh       = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->dbname};host={$this->dbhost};port={$this->dbport}", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass,array(
               PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
               PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
            ));
            $this->db        = true;
            echo '<p>made it</p>'; // Debug echo

            return true;

        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo '<p>'.$e->getMessage() . ' - Failing</p>';  // Debug echo
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password, $cookies = true){
        if($this->db === true){

            /* We Add LIMIT to 1 in SQL query because we need to just get an array of data with key as the column name. Nothing else. */

            if($this->emailLogin === true){
                $query = "SELECT `id`, `password`, `password_salt` FROM `{$this->dbtable}` WHERE `username`=:login OR `email`=:login ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1";
            }else{
                $query = "SELECT `id`, `password`, `password_salt` FROM `{$this->dbtable}` WHERE `username`=:login ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1";
            }
            echo "<pre>"; // Debug string
            var_dump($this->dbh); // Debug string
            echo "</pre>"; // Debug string

            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            $sql->bindValue(":login", $username);
            $sql->execute();

            if($sql->rowCount()==0){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = new LoginSystem();
$a->login('a','b');
```

I found that your code works when given proper credentials and a table name (which I assume you hard coded as those private vars) Also, the prepare warning you get usually means that `$this->dbh` is not the correct object or not defined so try adding the `var_dump()` where I have it and let us know what your `$this->dbh` is.

For some things you can try:

Please check your config on your db host, name, pass, port, etc

Also check that your PDO is enabled and check for your own error messages for more information

Finally storing your password_salt in your user database is generally not a good idea, it's the same as locking your house and putting your key under the doormat.

Comment: I check everything password PDO etc everything is fine

Comment: do you get the `"Made it!" ` debug message as well in your constructor? or do you get the `" Failing"` message with a warning?

Comment: trying to create connection

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out - Failing

NULL This is showing

Comment: You problem appears to be that you cannot connect to your database, please check your host and port and make sure your mysql is running

Comment: Let me check again